# Flask and Reactjs throw JSX Transform error

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

I have started using ReactJS with a Python Flask Backend.

I get the following client error in Chrome Console, when rendering the template via Flask.

> Error: Cannot find module
>   'jstransform/visitors/es6-templates-visitors'

**Server:**

```
@app.route("/")
def start():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**Client:**
index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/react.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/JSXTransformer.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/showdown.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div id="content"></div>

<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/golden-record.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this causing a problem, each file seems to be found within static. Why is JSX failing? 
Do I have to compile the JSX into Javascript first?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

**golden-record.js**

```
var SearchBox = React.createClass({...});

React.render(
    <SearchBox url="http://localhost:5000"/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Where is that module supposed to be loaded? Your client code doesn't seem to show it being needed. That said, yes, JSX always needs to be transformed either by precompiling (for production/live) or by loading the JSXtranformer alongside the react library client side (for dev testing)

Comment: I have added more details regarding the JSX content.  That should help, but how do you explain the JSX error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the problem.

The server runs on `127.0.0.1:5000.`

I had to change the Component to point to IP address instead of Localhost:

```
React.render(
    <SearchBox url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/search"/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Now it works. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: You can probably just do `/search`, and it'll be much more flexible.